# Cannot create shaders OpenGL 4.x

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, opengl, glsl, pdb-files

I am using [this tutorial](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-2-vertices-and-shapes/#toc-drawing-the-vbo-renderfunction). I have the correct hardware to run this (AMD 6870). I have followed the tutorial but I only get a flashing of the window before it exits. 
When I build the code, it builds fine, but lists a load of DLLs that cannot find a PDB. I stepped through my code (Im using Visual Studio 2010 prof) and it exited on my CreateShaders function with the error that they could not be created. I've checked the tutorial on that function and I have it copied.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#define WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX "Chapter Two - A Triangle"

    //Global variable dclerations
 int CurrentWidth  = 800;
int CurrentHeight = 600;
int WindowHandle  = 0;

unsigned FrameCount = 0;

GLuint 
vertexShaderId,
fragmentShaderId,
programId,
vaoId,
vboId,
colorBufferId;


//contents of GLSL vertexshader
const GLchar* vertexShader =
{
"version 400\n"\
"layout(location=0) in vec4 in_Position;\n"\
"layout(location=1) in vec4 in_Color;\n"\
"out vec4 ex_Color;\n"\

"void main(void)\n"\
"{\n"\
"   gl_Position = in_Position;\n"\
"   ex_Color = in_Color;\n"\
"}\n"

};

 //contents of fragment shader

 const GLchar* fragmentShader =
{
"#version 400\n"\

"in vec4 ex_Color;\n"\
"out vec4 out_Color;\n"\

"void main(void)\n"\
"{\n"\
"   out_Color = ex_Color;\n"\
"}\n"
 };

//prototypes
 void Initialize(int,char*[]);
void InitWindow(int, char*[]);
void ResizeFunction(int, int);
void RenderFunction(void);
void TimerFunction(int);
void IdleFunction(void);
void CleanUp(void);
void CreateVBO(void);
void DestroyVBO(void);
void CreateShaders(void);
void DestroyShaders(void);


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
Initialize(argc, argv);

glutMainLoop();

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


void Initialize(int argc, char* argv[])
{
GLenum GlewInitResult;

InitWindow(argc, argv);

//glew is initialised after the openGL context is created,
//it needs an active context to implement calls
GlewInitResult = glewInit();

//if glew did not init correctly, print errors
if(GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult)
{
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "ERROR: %s\n",
        glewGetErrorString(GlewInitResult)
        );
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fprintf(
    stdout,
    "INFO: OpenGL Version: %s\n",
    glGetString(GL_VERSION));

CreateShaders();
CreateVBO();
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f);

}

//uses freeglut to create a window
void InitWindow(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
//initialises freeglut library
glutInit(&argc, argv);

//creates a forward compatible OpenGL 4.0 core profile
glutInitContextVersion(4,0);
glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);

//when window closes, return to main loop
glutSetOption(
    GLUT_ACTION_ON_WINDOW_CLOSE,
    GLUT_ACTION_GLUTMAINLOOP_RETURNS
    );

glutInitWindowSize(CurrentWidth,CurrentHeight);

// enables depth buffer, double buffering, makes RGBA mode
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);

//makes window, passes it the value of defined window
WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

if(WindowHandle < 1)
{
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n"
        );
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//called when window is resized
glutReshapeFunc(ResizeFunction);
//called when scene is to be drawn on screen
glutDisplayFunc(RenderFunction);
glutIdleFunc(IdleFunction);
//(ms passed before func is called, func to call, value to pass)
glutTimerFunc(0,TimerFunction,0);
glutCloseFunc(CleanUp);
}

void ResizeFunction(int Width, int Height)
{
CurrentWidth = Width;
CurrentHeight = Height;
glViewport(0,0,CurrentWidth,CurrentHeight);
}

 void RenderFunction(void)
{
FrameCount++;
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,3);
glutSwapBuffers();
glutPostRedisplay();
}

 //redraws as soon as possible
void IdleFunction(void)
{
glutPostRedisplay();
}

void TimerFunction(int Value)
{
if(0 != Value)
{
    char* TempString = (char*)
        malloc(512 + strlen(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX));

    sprintf(
        TempString,
        "%s: %d Frames Per Second @ %d x %d",
        WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX,
        //update every quarter of a second
        FrameCount * 4,
        CurrentWidth,
        CurrentHeight
        );

    glutSetWindowTitle(TempString);
    free(TempString);
}

FrameCount = 0;
glutTimerFunc(250, TimerFunction,1);
}


void CleanUp (void)
{
DestroyShaders();
DestroyVBO();
}

void CreateVBO(void)
{
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.8f, -0.8f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f,   0.8f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.8f,   -0.8f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};

GLfloat colors[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};

GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoId);
glBindVertexArray(vaoId);

glGenBuffers(1, &vboId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,4,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glGenBuffers(1, &colorBufferId);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorBufferId);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glVertexAttribPointer(0,4,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
if (ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "ERROR: Could not create a VBO: %s \n",
        gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );

    exit(-1);
}


 }

 void DestroyVBO(void)
 {
GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

glDeleteBuffers(1, &colorBufferId);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vboId);

glBindVertexArray(0);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vaoId);

ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
if(ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "ERROR: Could not Destroy the VBO: %s \n",
        gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );
    exit(-1);
}
}

void CreateShaders(void)
{
GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

vertexShaderId =glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShaderId, 1, &vertexShader, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertexShaderId);

fragmentShaderId = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragmentShaderId, 1, &fragmentShader, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragmentShaderId);

programId = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(programId, vertexShaderId);
    glAttachShader(programId,fragmentShaderId);
glLinkProgram(programId);
glUseProgram(programId);

ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
if(ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "ERROR: Could not create the shaders: %s \n",
        gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );

    exit(-1);
}
 }

 void DestroyShaders(void)
{
GLenum ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();

glUseProgram(0);

glDetachShader(programId,vertexShaderId);
glDetachShader(programId,fragmentShaderId);


glDeleteShader(fragmentShaderId);
glDeleteShader(vertexShaderId);

glDeleteProgram(programId);


ErrorCheckValue = glGetError();
if(ErrorCheckValue != GL_NO_ERROR)
{
    fprintf(
        stderr,
        "Error: Could not destroy the shaders %s\n",
        gluErrorString(ErrorCheckValue)
        );
    exit(-1);
}

}
```

Comment: That tutorial shouldn't be used, if for no other reason than the fact that it doesn't do any shader compilation error checking.

Comment: Ok. Thanks :). Why is that a bad thing when it includes get error checking? Is it a case of being better to use or is it bad programming practise to use the latter or other reasons. Are there any other tutorials that you would recommend? I have looked on here for similar questions. Often the tutorials put forward include using pre make or cmake and I really just want to knuckle down and focus on a modern OpenGL approach at the moment.

Comment: "Why is that a bad thing when it includes get error checking?" It *doesn't* include [error checking;](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL#Error_Checking) that's why it's bad. Shader compilation failure doesn't give errors that are detectable with `glGetError`. The fact that the maker of that tutorial apparently didn't realize that is a serious problem, which suggests that the person doesn't know OpenGL as well as he thinks he does.

Comment: "I really just want to knuckle down and focus on a modern OpenGL approach at the moment." Graphics programming is not an appropriate subject for a beginning programmer. You need to be reasonably comfortable with C++ in general before you should start working in this direction. And if you're not comfortable enough to use a build system, then no graphics tutorial is really going to help you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again for your reply. I have some experience with c++ but not too much. This is why I'm also Learning that on the side. Unfortunately time is not with me as this is prep work for my final project in university in September. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL/PDB thing is normal, I don't think it has any effect on your code (I believe it involves loading debug information from DLLs, which is not required).

Shaders have their own error reporting mechanism that is outside of glGetError, you should add it to your code.

After compiling each individual shader, you want to call:

`glGetShaderiv` with option `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` (this returns true/false if compile was successful).

If compile failed, you can get the error message with `glGetShaderInfoLog`.

Then after linking the program, you want to call `glGetProgramiv` to get `GL_LINK_STATUS`, and again get the error message with `glGetProgramInfoLog`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will be able to try this when I get home tonight. Forgive me if this seems obvious but I'm not really that experienced with this. When you say call glGetShaderiv after each individual shader, that means I should call that after compiling vertexshaderid and after fragmentshaderid?  Also, what do you mean by after linking the program? Do you mean just after my includes?  Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: Yes, you check errors for each shader (vertex and fragment) individually after `glCompileShader`. When I say "after linking the program", I mean the next step after calling `glLinkProgram`. (I'm referring to the OpenGL program object, not your entire C++ program)